# json array converted to string in table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an HTML table where I am using AngularJS. What I am trying to achieve is simply make the array that returns, display as a regular string instead of an array. I also want to make the date display correctly as well.

```js
[{"userId":12,"username":"Smith, Al","date":"2018-03-07T01:00:07.895Z","value":"Pending; CA; good"}]
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'a regular string'? What would that json look like if displayed as a regular string?

Comment: `the date display correctly` - how does it "display" now?

Comment: There's no such thing as a JSON array. There are arrays, and there are JSON strings. What you have there is an array which contains a single object.

Comment: Please show how you are referencing the array in your view code, and how that doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: @Jaromanda X In reference to date not referencing correctly, I want the 2018-03-07 to show only and remove everything else behind that

Comment: a hint for the date issue: `"2018-03-07T01:00:07.895Z".substr(0,10)` or `"2018-03-07T01:00:07.895Z".split('T')[0]`

Comment: Do you want to display an array as a string? or show each array property? I don't understand. This is what you want? Print the json? https://plnkr.co/edit/0REe6vger25bJKOkXoAC?p=preview

Comment: You can try with JqGrid, which is used to display json data into table format look at this http://jsfiddle.net/amorris/yNw3C/, you can define your own formatter i.e. for your custom date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you want something like this:

```
<table>
<colgroup>
    <col style="width: 25%">
    <col style="width: 25%">
    <col style="width: 25%">
    <col style="width: 25%">
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>User Id</th>
    <th>User Name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Value</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr ng-repeat="obj in jsonArray">
    <td align="middle">{{ obj.userId }}</td>
    <td align="middle">{{ obj.username }}</td>
    <td align="middle">{{ obj.date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}</td>
    <td align="middle">{{ obj.value }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/b5sya2rzZnGRbakE26iu?p=preview

Comment: this was a nice setup!